# 3D Point inside object

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry

I have searched and searched for this question but I can't really understand any answer I found. My problem is quite simple:

Having one mesh (3D non-convex polygon built from triangles), I scan the space (xyz) and I need to find all the points that are "inside" the mesh for later processing. I repeat I've seen a lot of answers on this but I can't understand them.

Anyone around to help??

Comment: What do you mean by "all points"? There's an infinite amount of them, so you need to be more specific.

Comment: I mean those points that are scanned in space. To be more clear imagine a 3-for loop (x/y/z) which produces very specific 3D points. Some of them are inside the mesh, some are out. I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to find out if a given point is inside a mesh (otherwise, there is obviously an infinite amount of points).

A simple solution would be to cast a ray from that point (in any direction), and count the number of intersections with the triangles it intersects with. If the number is odd, the point is inside. When the ray hits an edge or a vertex, care must be taken to count that as one intersection.
Intersection of a ray and triangle is done by intersecting a line with a plane, checking that the point belongs to the ray and is inside the triangle.

Comment: i think that most propably that's the right algorithm to use. but still i've been trying to solve my problem this way and all i get is points everywhere. is there a sure/working code for triangle/ray intersection?

Comment: I could post a general algorithm, its fairly straightforward, except for the border cases (edge/vertex intersection), which need to be handled with care in the problem at hand. Alternatively, you could just pick another random direction and try again until you get no edge hits.

Comment: Anyway thank you, you helped me a lot by pointing me for sure to the ray/triangle intersection subject which i was kind of doubting. thank you again riv! :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking each point to see if it's inside the mesh will work, but we can do better from a performance perspective.
Your current approach will run in `O(x*y*z*t)`, given that the grid of points is `x` by `y` by `z`, and the mesh has `t` faces.

The alternative approach, which will run in `O(x*y*t)`, is to consider the grid lines passing through the mesh - find the points of intersection between the line and the mesh. There should be an even number of intersection points. Once these intersection points are sorted they define the regions of the line that lie inside the mesh.
It is then simple to generate the points on the line that lie in these regions.

Roughly (assuming that the mesh lies within the unit cube):

```
for each X in [0,1] {
  for each Y in [0,1] {
    Let P be a list of points of intersection between the mesh and the line from (X,Y,0) to (X,Y,1)
    Sort P into ascending order of z-coordinate
    Let I be false
    for each Z in [0,1] {
      if Z > P[0] {
        I = !I
        pop P[0] off the list
      }
      if( I ) {
        point (X,Y,Z) is inside the mesh
      }
    }
  }
}
```